# Laravel - Geeting input values while running api in postman in post method

Tags: laravel, api, postman

I am running API in postman. the code written in laravel. i cant able to get the input values while sending the values in post method. i am checking in the controller.

Comment: Welcome to Stack, please provide some code in order to resolve the issue.

Comment: Hello Welcome to StackOverflow, This question does not provide enough information always try to provide some information related to what you tried so far with some of your code. Help people to help you.

Comment: Please provide your code also

Answer (score 0):

#### Send data using postman

```
{
  "username":admin,
  "password":********
}
```

and write in your controller

```
public function login(Request $request){
    $inputdata = $request::all();
}
```

variable inputdata store your all input as an array

Comment: Thanks for your response, but am getting empty array while printing $inputdat. Please note that am giving inputs in form-data section in postman , and the method choose is post. please advice.

Comment: any comment on the above?

Answer (score 0):

You can get post variables using `Input`

For eg:

```
$username = Input::get('username');
```

Include `Input` package in your controller

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

Comment: thanks for your response , but it return empty while echo $username, Please advice

Comment: you need to add your parameters . This is just an example. Add your code and parameters you are passing from postman in your question.